# Help with power supply that only works when warm

Tags: power-supply, components, heat

When I power on the supply, The relays click for about a minute, and then it fully starts.

- I have replaced both relays, same story after replacing them.
- Moved on to all the electrolytic caps on the board, again same thing.
- Finally I replaced the IC's pointed out in the photos, but it STILL does the same thing.

What could be causing this? The replaced IC's are:
 IC REG LINEAR 3.3V 100MA SOT89-3 and IC REG LINEAR 12V 100MA SOT89-3, but it did not fix the problem.

[image: power supply]

Here is a link to other photos, my file size was too large for the site. https://photos.app.goo.gl/xs6r2cs4AraaxJor8

Comment: It looks like a garage door opener and there's always a chance that the bottom door edge detect circuit is faulty.

Comment: It’s controller for a motorized TV mount based on the silk legend.

Comment: I have looked at the other images. Too bad they're not of a higher resolution.

Comment: Is it actually getting warmer? Or are you just using the term "warm up" like we used to with old-fashioned valve TVs and radios?

Comment: Indeed its a TV control board.

Comment: Finbarr, I actually used hot air station, and it works every time. Otherwise from cold start, clicks and LED blinks, and then about 60 seconds later no more clicking, LED is steady and voltage is also steady.

Comment: Did you try warming up only certain parts of the board? That would bring you closer to the faulty part. Try warming up the U24 (TOP224) only, and I suspect it will work.

Comment: Off-Topic: I've never seen an open space optocoupler before. And I didn't expect to find one in a current product. Or wtf is this arrangement in the upper right of the assembly? At least, very awkward design.

Answer (score 3):

I would look for a bad solder joint or a poor connection somewhere. Thermal expansion and contraction can change a marginal connection into no connection at all. An easy thing to do is to reflow all of the solder joints (that you haven't already redone).

Answer (score 2):

A power supply working only when it's warm usually indicates bad electrolytic capacitors.
In case of a switching power supply, it could also indicate that your capacitors do not have a low enough ESR (equivalent series resistance).
If you have replaced them, chances are they are not of a sufficiently low ESR and that your circuit requires better ones (lower ESR).
 However, I have looked at the specs of your capacitors (Nichicon PW series) and they are the low ESR type, so it is likely something else.

Comment: I was going to mention, I made sure to get quality caps with exact values. I do appreciate your input. Before even posting this, my next suspect was the little yellow ceramic cap on lower left side of board. But then again, at this point I am just throwing stuff at the wall to see if it sticks. EDIT: I also forgot to mention, when first turned on, the relays click, the LED blinks and voltage goes right along with it. Spikes when the relays click and low voltage when LED turns off. I am not sure if that is any help.

Comment: Have you replaced the electrolytic cap (C3) next to the supply chip U24 (TOP224)?

Comment: Edin, no, actually that is the only cap that did not get replaced.

Comment: That could be your culprit. It is right next to the power supply IC which gets very warm (or even hot) during operation, and this evaporates the electrolyte from the cap. That should have been the first one to replace.

Comment: Edin (or anybody), I have added photos to my album of C3, although I am having a difficult time identifying it.

Comment: It is a 47µF cap, but I am not sure if that is a 10 or a 40 (stands for voltage in volts).

Comment: Under the scope it looks as if it is a 40v. But after looking at my local supplier, they don't have 40v but do have 10v, here is a link to the product. Is this correct? https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/united-chemi-con/APXE100ARA470ME61G/565-3197-2-ND/1826661

Comment: OK, I checked the TOP224 datasheet, and it's a 10V cap. So, you need a 47µF, 10V cap.

Comment: I figured. Thanks so much, now lets hope that takes care of the issue!

Comment: You could try using one from some other electronics board to see if it will solve your issue. Do you have any way of measuring the capacitance of that cap?

Comment: No, but I am going to invest in a ESR meter. I just have a very basic multi-meter. No worries though, the supplier is here in town and it will be in the mailbox in the morning.

Comment: Have you heard of Daqarta (www.daqarta.com). It's a program you can use to measure a capacitor's ESR down to 1mΩ (0.001Ω) using your sound card. All you need is a simple circuit with a single resistor as a reference and a sound card with a stereo (Line) input. Fully functioning for free for 30 days or 30 times use. Afterwards you just reinstall it. Here is exact URL about their LCR test: http://www.daqarta.com/dw_0o0z.htm

Comment: That is simply amazing, I have been around the Electronics and micro-soldering community for some years now and I have never heard or seen anything such as this. Great share Edin, I will keep you posted if that little SMD cap WAS the culprit. If not, my next guess would be a thermistor. I believe it is the little yellow component in the lower left of the board. (But I rarely see that be a problem) Again, thanks for your help, and you and your family please be safe!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to be of help. If you need any further pointers about that program, feel free to ask. I have found it very helpful and quite accurate. Those people deserve some awards for such a great program. Geniuses.

Comment: Edin Fifić, I am happy to say that you were correct in the C3 cap was bad. Repealed and replaced and the problem is gone. Thanks so much for your help in this matter.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked. Did you try Daqarta? What do you think about it? Finally, would you mark my answer as the accepted one? Thank you.

Comment: Edin, I have not tried Daqarta...although I will when this global craziness settles down. I would love to mark the answer as the accepted one, but the post was closed by admins saying it was "off topic". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an inrush-limiting NTC in the primary? That could be on the fritz. NTCs have higher resistance until they warm up. It could be a little *too* high for the supply to start up reliably. NTCs look a bit like thick disc capacitors.

It looks like it’s that yellow component next to the CM choke and the 0.1uF cap, at lower left. That’s where I’d expect one to be. You can measure  the DC resistance across it to check.

More about what NTCs are, and how they’re used to limit inrush current in power supplies: https://www.powerelectronics.com/community/article/21860750/how-do-you-choose-the-right-type-of-ntc-thermistor-to-limit-inrush-current-for-capacitive-applications

Comment: That could be the yellow one in the picture, but it doesn't look defective (not that it has to look bad in order to be bad).

Comment: Worth mentioning: an inrush current limiting NTC is one of the few things you actually *can* test in circuit, just due to the way it's connected (anything that would interfere with the measurement would also either interfere with its current-limiting function or just not make sense to put there)